# Getting an error when executing "chkconfig --add tomcat" using chef?

Tags: tomcat, centos, chef-infra

I am using chef to configure a centos machine and everything is installing fine except for

```
execute "chkconfig add tomcat" do
  command "chkconfig --add tomcat"
end

execute "chkconfig tomcat level" do
  command "chkconfig --level 234 tomcat on"
end
```

Which brings this error..

```
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of chkconfig --add tomcat ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: error reading information on service tomcat: No such file or directory
---- End output of sudo chkconfig --add tomcat ----
Ran chkconfig --add tomcat returned 1
```

Comment: `tomcat` isn't in your `$PATH`...

Answer (score 1):

Are you married to using `chkconfig`? There's a [service](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_service.html) resource that should take care of this for you.

> Chef::Provider::Service::Init::Redhat service The provider that is used with the Red Hat and CentOS platforms.

Answer (score 1):

```
service "tomcat" do
  supports :status => true, :restart => true, :reload => true
  action [ :enable, :start ]
end
```